# Makefile path directory using ~/

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to compile a test through a make file. Why does the first path with ~/ not compile, while the second with the full path work. ARen't they the equivalent? Should I avoid using ~/ in makefiles?

This did not compile:

> g++ -isystem ~/workspace/gtest-1.7.0/include -I~/workspace/gtest-1.7.0
>   -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -c \
>               ~/workspace/gtest-1.7.0/src/gtest-all.cc /home/olivier/workspace/gtest-1.7.0/src/gtest-all.cc:42:24: fatal
>
> error: src/gtest.cc: No such file or directory #include "src/gtest.cc"

This compiled fine:

> g++ -isystem /home/olivier/workspace/gtest-1.7.0/include
>   -I/home/olivier/workspace/gtest-1.7.0 -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread -c \
>               /home/olivier/workspace/gtest-1.7.0/src/gtest-all.cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` expansion doesn't generally work in the middle of a string. The shell that Make is using doesn't know what to do with `-I~/whatever`. Try relative paths instead, or if you absolutely need an equivalent of `~`, try `$(HOME)`.

Comment: You can also add a space between `-I` and the argument: `-I ~/whatever`.  It's not required that they be a single argument.  Then the shell will see that it can expand the `~`.